# gmap dragging using left mouse button

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I'm using the gmap.net control to display the maps on windows forms.as of now everything works fine except the map dragging functionality.in general map dragging is supported with Left-Mouse Button , but in gmap.net control dragging is supported with Right-Mouse button.

Here my question is :
Is there any way by which I can achieve the Map Dragging functionality using Left-Mouse  Button.

Please Help Me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I have found the answer, it is just setting the `DragButton` property of `GMAP` control

```
MainGMap.DragButton = MouseButton.Left;
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the accepted answer, I had to change `MouseButton` to `MouseButtons` for it to work:

```
MainGMap.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
```